# replacement for guild.roles.find() in newer versions of discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've been coding a discord bot in discord.js, and I need a way to recognize a role by its name, so I looked up how to do that in the documentation, but couldn't find exactly what I was looking for (I'm very new to javascript, so I might have seen what I was looking for but just not understood it. That's also why the code will likely make you cringe.) I looked up how to do this online, and everyone said to use the guild.roles.find() function, so I put it into my code and when it didn't work. I then looked for the guild.roles.find() function in the documentation, and it wasn't there at all, leading me to believe it had been deleted. If anyone knows the solution to this, it would be much appreciated.

`let role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === stringSplit[i]);`

(`stringSplit[i]` is the name of the role which has been input by a user.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the roles of a certain guild you can do

```
const roles = message.guild.roles.cache.array();
```

Now you can filter these roles to get the one you want with the name property.

`message.guild.roles.cache` returns a collection: you can take a look here for all the available methods: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Do you mind explaining to a new script coder how this works? I'm making discord bots to better my Javscript so that I can make more complicated API-based bots for other applications.

Comment: @tuxfrog Well there is not much explaining to do but if it is about learning I would really suggest to just read the documentation carefully. If you take a look at the docs you can see all the classes. And every method or property gives you a class of another type back or collections, ... Also if you would like to better your knowledge about js I would read MDN docs and try to build some kind of application yourself. For me personally I learn best out of reading docs, if something is very unclear I watch a video or read a blog post. Success!

Answer (score 0):

You can access `roles` collection using `cache`.

Your solution would be:

```js
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === stringSplit[i]);
```